# PPS Status for Oncore Reference clock?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I've just hooked up an old VP Oncore to a Raspberry PI (using a PPS kernel) and have the following...

```
root@ntpi:/var/log# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*GPS_ONCORE(0)   .GPS.            0 l    6   16  377    0.000    0.004   0.003
+ptbtime1.ptb.de .PTB.            1 u   40   64  377   32.704   -0.295   0.585
-smn.pecs.hpc.ni 185.219.2.214    2 u   35   64  377   47.220    0.136   0.267
-pool.ntp.connec 192.36.144.22    2 u   43   64  377   74.129   -0.308   3.224
+stratum2-2.NTP. 129.70.130.70    2 u   25   64  377   31.977    0.078   2.104
-service0-eth4.d 193.171.23.163   2 u   30   64  377   48.827   -0.899   0.780
root@ntpi:/var/log#
```

Is this correct?  i.e. would I expect the terminal state to be "*" i.e. System rather than "o" PPS?

Thanks in advance
Nivag

Answer (score 0):

Bug in ntp-dev-4.2.7p319

Fixed Bug and raised issue with NTP Support via BugZilla

```
root@ntpi:/build/ntp-dev-4.2.7p319# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
oGPS_ONCORE(0)   .GPS.            0 l    8   16  377    0.000   -0.028   0.003
*ptbtime1.ptb.de .PTB.            1 u   31   64   77   38.165   -0.358   3.204
+frankfurt1.firs 161.62.157.173   3 u   23   64   77   31.150   -2.657   0.614
+diane.ensma.fr  140.203.204.77   2 u   17   64   77   44.583   -2.761   2.538
+iris.wf-hosting 105.240.56.33    2 u   18   64   77   16.818   -2.137   2.243
+login-vlan87.bu 165.94.197.40    2 u   21   64   77   48.778   -0.902   2.249
root@ntpi:/build/ntp-dev-4.2.7p319#
```